# After moving site to other host, i get 404 on posts

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I moved my site from host A to host B. Now homepage opens and shows posts but when I click on any post or page, it gives `404` error.

I changed `.htaccess` file with various variations but no result. When I changed permalinks to default (?=id), it started working fine.

Now if I change permalinks back to postnames, it again gives `404` error.

My site is `http://mixapk.net/`

Comment: Can you show how your postname url looks like ?

Comment: Here it is https://mixapk.net/wrestling-revolution-3d-1-890-mod-unlocked-apk/ and same post with default link  http://mixapk.net/?p=55643

Answer (score 0):

According to this [this](http://www.howtosolutions.net/2017/07/wordpress-fixing-not-found-error-when-using-pretty-permalinks/) article, main reason for this might be the server configuration missing **mod_rewrite** module being loaded.